# Disable "change account settings" in start menu option of Windows 10

Tags: powershell

Is there any way to disable "change account settings" in start menu options other than using the registry key "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer" registry hive with key name "NocontrolPanel" and value is "1". If the above key is enabled entire control panel doesnt show up along with the disable of change account settings which is not required.I only need to disable change account settings.

I tried using gpo which gives total disablement of control panel. Is there any solution to disable change account settings only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be also done in group policy settings. Please follow the below steps,

1. Press ***Windows + R*** key and type ***gpedit.msc***.
2. Goto ***Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>Control Panel>User Accounts***
3. Double click on "***Apply the default account picture to all users.***"
4. And select the Option ***Enabled*** and click ***Ok***.

This will hide the change account settings option. And also you can access the control panel

Please accept the answer if it solved your issue! Have a great day!

Comment: do we have any other option other than group policy?

Comment: @Hidel, This seems to be the best solution for your scenario. Why it doesn't work or do you face any other issues?

Answer (score 0):

This change can be made via the Registry. Please run the following from a command prompt.

CMD.exe :

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Start\HideChangeAccountSettings" /t "REG_DWORD" /v "value" /d "1" /f
```

PowerShell :

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PolicyManager\default\Start\HideChangeAccountSettings" -Type "DWord" -Name "value" -Value "1" -Force
```